# find values in dictionary keys for which values are not equal

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list:
x=[{'569014_JR1208': 'COMPL'}, {'607923_A0763': 'ERROR'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}, {'569014_JR1208': 'ERROR'}, {'646170_1NK3XJ': 'ERROR'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}]

I want to identify the keys for which there are multiple values which are not equal.

In this case, it should return only 569014_JR1208

I think this can be solved by dict comprehension, but not able to get a way around it.

Thanks a lot for the help,
Sudip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
x=[{'569014_JR1208': 'COMPL'}, {'607923_A0763': 'ERROR'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}, {'569014_JR1208': 'ERROR'}, {'646170_1NK3XJ': 'ERROR'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}]

res = {}

for dict in x:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if res.get(key) and value not in res[key]:
            # the value is different
            print(key)
        if not res.get(key):
            res[key] = value
```

Result is: 569014_JR1208

Comment: thanks a lot mate, yep, this should work well

Answer (score 0):

I`m not really skillful programmer, so don't beat me. I think, I have done it in some not really effective way, but that was a nice challange for me. So here is what I got:

```
x = [{'569014_JR1208': 'COMPL'}, {'607923_A0763': 'ERROR'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'},
     {'569014_JR1208': 'ERROR'}, {'646170_1NK3XJ': 'ERROR'}, {'564849_1H435': 'COMPL'}]

def find_key_with_2_different_values(list_of_dictionaries):
    helping_dictionary = {}

    for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
        key = list(dictionary.keys())[0]
        if key not in helping_dictionary:
            helping_dictionary[key] = [dictionary[key]]
        else:
            helping_dictionary[key].append(dictionary[key])

    for key in helping_dictionary:
        results = helping_dictionary[key]
        for i in range(len(results) - 1):
            if results[i] != results[i + 1]:
                # print(f"key {key} has both {results[i]} and {results[i + 1]} values")
                return key

print(find_key_with_2_different_values(x))  # should print "569014_JR1208"
```